# Android Communicating with a Processing Sketch over USB

Tags: android, usb, processing

I'm looking for a way to use an android processing sketch to send data back to a Java processing sketch running on my computer over USB. Anyone know if and how this is possible?
Thanks!

Comment: what did you have so far?

Comment: I haven't done it through usb/serial yet, but it's fairly easy to do it wirelessly with OscP5 (which also works on non-Processing Android SDK projects)

Answer (score 0):

Processing's **Android Mode** could make your android device and computer communicating via USB.